# How to getIDs of SVG Paths

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I'm currently working on this svg file and I'm trying to get the ID of each path. I converted the image using Raphael so this was the code.
[Image of path code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrnU6.png)

Then here's my svg in my html file.

[Image of svg code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dndqa.png)

Comment: replace those images with code asap

Comment: @madalinivascu I did try it, works but it's gonna be a lot of work since I'm making it for the entire University. Thanks though

Comment: are you afraid someone will use / rip off your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just loop over all path elements and read their id...

```js
document.querySelectorAll("path").forEach(function(item) {
  document.write(item.id + "<br/>")
})
```

```html
<svg height="0px">
  <path id="id1" d=""/>
  <path id="id2" d=""/>
  <path id="id3" d=""/>
  <path id="id4" d=""/>
  <path id="id5" d=""/>
</svg>
<br/>
```